# Export MS SQL table with `null` values to CSV

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I am trying to figure out how to create a csv file that contains the `null` values I have in my MS SQL database table. Right now the script I am using fills up the `null` values with `''` (empty strings). How I am supposed to instruct the csv Writer to keep the null values?

example of source table

```
ID,Date,Entitled Key
10000002,NULL,805
10000003,2020-11-22 00:00:00,805
```

export_sql_to_csv.py

```
import csv
import os
import pyodbc

filePath = os.getcwd() + '/'
fileName = 'rigs_latest.csv'

server = 'ip-address'
database = 'db-name'
username = 'admin'
password = 'password'

# Database connection variable.
connect = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +
                                 server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD=' + password)
cursor = connect.cursor()

sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM my_table"


cursor.execute(sqlSelect)
results = cursor.fetchall()

# Extract the table headers.
headers = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]

# Open CSV file for writing.
csvFile = csv.writer(open(filePath + fileName, 'w', newline=''),
                     delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r\n',
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')

# Add the headers and data to the CSV file.
csvFile.writerow(headers)
csvFile.writerows(results)
```

Example of the result after running the above script:

```
ID,Date,Entitled Key
10000002,,805
10000003,2020-11-22 00:00:00,805
```

The main reason why I would like to keep the `null` values is that I would like to convert that `csv` file into series of insert SQL statements and execute those against Aurora Serverless PostgreSQL database. The database doesn't accept empty strings for the type `date` and results in that error: `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""`

Comment: What would you like the CSV file to contain? Anyway, as it is a **text** file, it can only contain string values, delimited with a separator (here the comma). But if you know which columns have to be tweaked and which values you would like instead of empty strings, it is easy to replace the relevant empty values in the Python script...

Comment: Ideally, I would like to keep the `NULL` values that I have in my db so that when I use that csv file to generate SQL statements the `NULL` values will go into them as well instead of empty strings. 

I think I only need the NULL `DATE` type columns from my MS SQL db to be saved as `NULL` values instead of `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [docs for the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer), the `None` value is written to CSV as `''` (empty string) by design. All other non-string values call `str` first.

So if you want your CSV to have the string `null` instead of `''` then you have to modify the values before they reach the CSV writer. Perhaps:

```
results = [
['null' if val is None else val for val in row] for row in results
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, James. That resulted in adding `'null'` values into the generated `CSV` file as expected. I had to modify my `csv_to_sql` python script a bit to accommodate for that change and now it generates `sql` statements with `NULL` values properly :)